# Typescript has no autocomplete (mark with any if nested object)

Tags: typescript

I'm new with typescript and try to type `myVar` with type which i created but the problem is that typescript do not provide me hints when nested object and mark `interface NameProperties as any`

I wonder why, and how can i fix it?

```
interface NameProperties {
  [value: string]: string,
}


type Filter = {
  name: NameProperties,
  company: NameProperties
}


interface  Filters<T> {

  first: number,
  rows: number,
  page: number,
  sortField: boolean,
  sortOrder: boolean,
  filters: T
}


const myVar: Filters<Filter> = {
  first: 1,
  rows: 10,
  page: 2,
  sortField: false,
  sortOrder: false,


  filters:{
    name: // no hints TS2741: Property 'company' is missing in type '{ name: any; }' but required in type 'Filter'. 

  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain the actual and expected behaviour? It is not clear which part of the compiler output is surprising and what hints you expect.

Comment: What hints are you expecting?  What does "mark `interface NameProperties as any`" mean?

Comment: @Lesiak the problem is typescript mark any property name on filter. I expect that it shows  (name: {value: string})

Comment: @jcalz the problem is typescript mark any property name on filter. I expect that it shows (name: {value: string}) please see screenshot above

Comment: Error messages aren't IntelliSense hints, I'm not sure why you expect anything in particular inside an error message.

Comment: @jcalz why it says that {name: any}?, instead of {name: {value: string}}

Comment: The value in question is `{name: }` which is syntactically invalid.  What is the type of `{name: }`? There's no property value so type inference *fails* and the compiler usually produces `any` in such situations. Again, I don't know why you'd expect anything in particular from the errors produced by syntactically invalid code. It's not a *hint*, it's an *error*. It's talking about the invalid value you gave, not the value it expects.